# if $\lvert f \rvert + \lvert g\rvert$ is bounded then are both $f$ and $g$ are also bounded?

Tags: functions

I am confused about bounded functions with absolute values:

if $\lvert f \rvert + \lvert g\rvert$ is bounded then are both $f$ and $g$ also bounded?

Comment: Yes, since $|f|,\,|g|\le |f|+|g|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
$$|f| + |g| < +\infty$$
implies
$$|f| < +\infty \quad \text{and} \quad  |g| < +\infty$$
since $|f| ,|g| \leq |f| + |g|$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

By definition of boundedness, there exists an element $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f|+ |g| \leq M$

Now, $$f,g  \leq |f+g| \leq |f| +|g| \leq M$$ such that $f,g$ are bounded